# Referencing an input :(

Tags: android, random, generator

i was wondering if anyone could tell me how to use my input/EditText as the value for the max value (line 15, where the `.nextInt(1000)` is) for this random number generator. I've tried looking up how to do it and asked. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Random;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button pushMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    pushMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String randText = "";
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Random randGen = new Random();
            int rando = randGen.nextInt(1000) + 1;
            randText = Integer.toString(rando);
            textOne.setText(randText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you be little more specific ?Where is your EditText and what is line 15 ?

Comment: can you post your activity_main xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an EditText in your layout with `android:id="@+id/editText1"`, then this would be one way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    Button pushMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);        
    pushMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Random randGen = new Random();
                String randText = "";
                int max = 0;

                String input = editText.getText().toString();

                try
                {
                    max = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    int rando = randGen.nextInt(max) + 1;
                    randText = Integer.toString(rando);
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
                {
                    randText = "Invalid input";
                }

                textOne.setText(randText);
            }
        }
    ); 
}
```

Please note that `catch (IllegalArgumentException e)` will catch both the `IllegalArgumentException` that `Random.nextInt()` can throw, as well as the `NumberFormatException` that `Integer.parseInt()` can throw.